# No mostrar ciertos registros en una consulta sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy realizando un sistema de cursos online, y en la lista de todos los cursos ofrecidos al público quisiera obviar los que el usuario en sesion ya compró.

Tengo dos tablas que son:

**Cursos:**

```
|-----------|---------------|------------|
| idcurso   | nombre        | descripcion| 
|-----------|---------------|------------|
| 2547      | Html 5 + Css3 |   texto    | 
|-----------|---------------|------------|
| 2555      | Javascript    |   texto    | 
|-----------|---------------|------------|
| 2568      | PHP           |   texto    | 
|-----------|---------------|------------|
```

Otra tabla llamada **usuariosxcursos**, donde se almacenan los cursos adquiridos por los usuarios

```
|------------------|--------|------------|-------------------|
| id_usuarioxcurso | iduser | idcurso    | fecha_inscripcion |
|------------------|--------|------------|-------------------|
| 1                |   1    |   2547     |    2018-04-07     |
|------------------|--------|------------|-------------------|
| 2                |   2    |   2547     |    2018-04-07     |
|------------------|--------|------------|-------------------|
```

La consulta en sí, asumiendo que el id del usuario en sesion es **1**, debería mostrar los cursos de Javascript y PHP. Anteriormente realicé un join de las dos tablas que es la siguiente:

```
SELECT  c.idcurso, c.nombre_curso, c.descripcion, u.iduser, u.idcurso FROM cursos c LEFT JOIN usuarioxcursos u ON c.idcurso=u.idcurso
```

Con esa sentencia obtengo todos, pero el error que tengo que, aunque con php logre quitar el idcurso del usuario en sesion, me muestra los de los otros usuarios. Ejemplo:
Si  el 
usuario 1, usuario 2, usuario 3, tienen el mismo curso comprado en los resultados tendría repetido idcurso repetido 2 veces. (Nota: en la consulta inicial serían 3 veces repetidos el idcurso) Mi deseo es que si usuario 1 tiene adquirido el curso de Html 5 + css3, en los resultados tenga:

```
|-----------|---------------|------------|
| idcurso   | nombre        | descripcion| 
|-----------|---------------|------------|
| 2555      | Javascript    |   texto    | 
|-----------|---------------|------------|
| 2568      | PHP           |   texto    | 
|-----------|---------------|------------|
```

Si alguien pudiese ayudarme, gracias con anticipación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar la clausula `NOT IN` para descartar aquellos cursos de un usuario que se encuentran en la tabla `usuarioxcursos`.

Haciendo algo así:

```
SELECT  
  c.idcurso, 
  c.nombre_curso, 
  c.descripcion
FROM cursos c 
WHERE c.idcurso NOT IN 
(
  SELECT u.idcurso FROM usuarioxcursos u WHERE u.iduser=1
);
```

Un ejemplo completo para hacer pruebas lo puedes ver [aquí](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rZrkfk4NjxjmV2Nm5Y25QV/0)

```
CREATE TABLE cursos (
  idcurso INT,
  nombre_curso text,
  descripcion text
);

CREATE TABLE usuarioxcursos (
  id INT,
  iduser INT,
  idcurso INT,
  fecha_inscripcion DATE
);

INSERT INTO cursos (idcurso, nombre_curso, descripcion) VALUES 
(2547, 'html', 'esto es html'),
(2568, 'php', 'esto es php'),
(2555, 'JS', 'esto es js');

INSERT INTO usuarioxcursos (id, iduser, idcurso, fecha_inscripcion) VALUES 
(1, 1, 2547, '2018-04-07'),
(2, 2, 2547, '2018-04-07');


SELECT * FROM usuarioxcursos;

SELECT  
  c.idcurso, 
  c.nombre_curso, 
  c.descripcion
FROM cursos c 
WHERE c.idcurso NOT IN 
(
  SELECT u.idcurso FROM usuarioxcursos u WHERE u.iduser=1
);
```

Resultado:

```
idcurso | nombre_curso | descripcion
------------------------------------
2568    | php          | esto es php
2555    | JS           | esto es js
```

Comment: ¡Wuao! Muchas gracias, no lo había visto de ese modo. ¡Eres genial!

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que no estás filtrando los datos para el usuario actual, es decir que te hace falta un where en la consulta algo así:

```
Where idusuario = $usuarioactual
```

Espero sea de ayuda y solucione tu problema

Comment: Sí, sí, cuando añadía el WHERE $iduser <> '1', me deja sólo los datos de la tabla usuarioxcursos

Comment: si te sirvio mi respuesta, porfavor marcala como correcta o compartenos  tu solucion @Christina

Comment: No, corazón, no me ha servido. Sólo te aclaré que me mostraba datos que no necesitaba :(

Comment: solo agrega un WHERE y la columna q quieres filtrar ponle la sentencia correspondiente